# Calling a function recursively in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

The below code returns `UUID` in V4 format i.e `8-4-4-4-12` for a total of `36` characters. I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/60074845/3747770 to generate the UUID.

```
<func:function name="Utility:getFormatedV4Uuid">
    <func:result>
        <xsl:text>uuid.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Utility:UUID4()"/>
    </func:result>
</func:function>
```

But the issue is the function `Utility:UUID4` some time returns `35` characters instead of `36` characters and I am unable to reproduce the issue.
So I am planning to recursively call the `Utility:UUID4` function until it returns `36` characters.
How do I recursively call a function `Utility:UUID4` until it returns `36` characters in XSLT 1.0?
Or, is there anyway to fix the issue?

Comment: You can call a *named template* recursively. Not sure that's the best solution, though. Might be better to fix the problem at its source - but you're not revealing what it is. BTW, `func:function` is not XSLT 1.0; it's an EXSLT extension.

Comment: Updated the question with the link which I am using to generate the UUID.

Comment: Oh, that one. I told you at a comment there that I cannot understand how this problem is possible - let alone reproduce it.

Comment: I used oxygen tool for testing the UUID code. I generated around 500 UUIDs and did check the length, it was okay. I am using this UUID code along with many other xslt files, occasionally I get this length error. We use these XSLT files for generating IWXXM METAR/SPECI gmlid's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I don't know how to reproduce the problem.

To answer your question: you could call the calling function recursively until the called function returns a satisfactory result:

```
<func:function name="Utility:getFormatedV4Uuid">
    <xsl:variable name="uid" select="Utility:UUID4()"/>
    <func:result>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($uid) = 36">
                <xsl:text>uuid.</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$uid"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="Utility:getFormatedV4Uuid()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </func:result>
</func:function>
```

Untested, because I don't know how to test it without being able to reproduce the problem.